# Efficient way to sort a concatenation of lists (STL), merge sort hint, partially sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a situation where I get a list of values that are already partially sorted. There are N blocks in my final list, each block is sorted. So I end up having a list of data like this (slashes are just for emphasis):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 / 1 2 3 4 5 / 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 / 1 2 3 4
```

I have these in a vector as a series of pointers to the objects. Currently I just use `std::sort` with a custom comparator to the sorting. I would guess this is sub-optimal as my sequence is some degenerate case.

Are there any other stl functions, hints, or otherwise that I could use to provide an optimal sort of such data?  (Boost libraries are also fine).

*Though I can't easily break up the input data I certainly can determine where the sub-sequences start.*

Comment: I believe for linked lists merge sort is one of the few algorithms that work well.

Comment: By *list* I meant just the abstract data structure. They are actually stored in a `std::vector` at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [`std::merge`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/), although this algorithm can only merge **two** sorted collections at a time, so you would have to call it in a loop. Also note that `std::list` provides `merge` as a member function.

**EDIT** Actually [`std::inplace_merge`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/inplace_merge/) might be an even better candidate.

Comment: The run-time complexity is the same as merge sort here. *O(n * log(n))*. The less sublists the better your runtime. For only 2 sublists it's actually *O(n)*.

Comment: I can't easily break the data up into independent lists to do the merge sort. I would have to create two temporary lists and go one sub-set at a time. I could try it I guess, the memory allocation of the list may be more expensive than an inefficient sort.

Comment: @edA-qa: You don't have to split them up. [std::merge](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/algorithm/merge) allows you to specify a start and an end element. If you're concerned about memory, you might want to take a look at [std::inplace_merge](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/algorithm/inplace_merge)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I looked at the "merge" in the list class first. But the standalone function does indeed take arbitrary sequences. I'll have to compare doing it this way vs. the multiway_merge.

Comment: I didn't even knew there was such a beast as `inplace_merge` in the standard library! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This calls for a “multiway merge”. The standard library doesn’t have an appropriate algorithm for that. However, the parallel extension of the GCC standard library does:

[`__gnu_parallel::multiway_merge`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01128.html#a82b81744e4f5f55c8e8425c35a61fadb).

Comment: This looks like I could actually make it work without dynamic memory allocation. Thanks!

Comment: This is a bad idea, it's not standard and might change. Try to find something a bit more standard if possible. Or submit a feature request into boost.

Comment: I do prefer standard, but non-standard doesn't bother me. I already use several GCC builtins in this part of the code.

Comment: @the_drow: there is no “standard” library function to do that. Furthermore, this API will *not* change. It is a documented and published API for public consumption. Furthermore, the license actually allows copying the code so this solution can even be used in a non-GCC environment (although that might admittedly require some tweaking, which in turn means that the changes must be published under GPL with runtime exception). The solution is far from perfect but using a multiways merge is *the* canonical way of solving this problem and this is the only usable and free implementation that I know.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate on all of the lists at once, keeping and index for each list. and comparing only items in that index.

this can be significantly faster than regular sort : O(n) vs O(n*log(n)) where n is the number of items in all the lists.

see the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) article.

C++ has std::merge for it, but it will not handle multiple lists at once so you may want to craft your own version which does.

Comment: If you do this wrong, you'll actually increase your total comparisons.

Comment: This breaks down if there are many sublists. In the worst case of having *n* sublists, you've got a run-time complexity of *O(n²)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spare the memory, mergesort will perform very well for this.  For best results, merge the smallest two chains at a time, until you only have one.

Comment: Does the order of merging really matter?

Comment: The closer the lists are in size, the fewer average comparisons are required per merge.  Building from the bottom up gives you an optimal comparison count without having to do much planning work.  You can make slight improvements to cache performance with some trickier planning, but it's really not worth it.